# C File Handling not printing data from text file properly

Tags: c, file-handling

I currently have a homework on C/C++ File Handling (I thought we would be learning C++ but it looks like we are learning C instead). When it comes to printing data from a text file, it does not print it correctly and also it prints random characters.

```
void show(void){
    system("cls");
    int singapore, spain, hawaii, southKorea, firstClass, businessClass, economyClass, age, row=10;
    char utic[10], name[20], destination[20], classType[20];
    line2(2,2,78,24);
    line1(3,3,77,5);
    line1(3,7,77,22);
    center(4,"Show Existing Record");
    gotoxy(5,8);
    printf("UTIC\tName\t\t\Age\tDestination\tClass\t\tDate");
    hline(4,9,76,196);
    FILE *textfile;
    textfile=fopen("ticket list.txt", "r");
    while(fscanf(textfile,"%s %s %d %s %s",utic,name,&age,destination,classType)!=EOF){
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
        gotoxy(5,8);
        printxy(5,8,"UTIC\tName\t\t\Age\tDestination\tClass\t\tDate");
        gotoxy(5,row);
        printf("%s",utic);
        gotoxy(15,row);
        printf("%s",name);
        gotoxy(25,row);
        printf("%d",age);
        gotoxy(35,row);
        printf("%s",destination);
        gotoxy(45,row);
        printf("%s",classType);
        row++;
    }//while
```

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxR2D.png)

Here's the data from the text file

```
/*UTIC0 Jose Santos 10 Spain First Class
UTIC2 Juan Cruz 18 South Korea Economy Class*/
```

I am using my prof's code as a reference. Here it is:

```
else if (ans=='C')
{
int row=7;
system("cls");
fp=fopen("student.txt","r");
printxy(5,5, "Student #\(tStudent name\tMidterm\tFinals");
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s *f *f", snum, Iname, fname, &mt,&fn) I=EOF)
gotoxy (5, row) ;printf("%s\t¥s %s", snum, fname, Iname);
gotoxy (35, row) ;printf("%.2f", mt);
gotoxy(45,row);printf("%.2f",fn);
row++:
}
getch();
fclose(fp);
}
```

[My prof's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjF77.png)

Here's my entire code:

```
#include"myfunctions.h"
#include<string.h>

//Asks user to generate a new text file.
void generate(void){
    char response;
    FILE *textfile;
    center(23,"Generating a new file overwrites the old one. Press 'y' to proceed");
    response = toupper(getch());
    if(response=='Y'){
    
        textfile = fopen("ticket list.txt","w");
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
        for(int x=4;x<=76;x++)
        {
            gotoxy(x,23);
            putchar(219);
            Sleep(25);
        }
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
        center(23, "File generation complete. Press any key to continue...");
        getch();
    }
    else{
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
        center(23, "User cancelled. Press any key to continue...");
        getch();
    }
} //void generate

//Asks user to insert a new entry. 
void insert(void){
    char ans,name[20],utic[10],destinationAsk,destination[20],classTypeAsk,classType[20];
    int age;
    FILE *textfile;
    system("cls");
    //Screen layout
    line2(2,2,78,24);
    line1(3,3,77,5);
    line1(3,8,77,22);
    center(4,"Insert new record");
    hline(4,11,76,196);
    hline(4,13,76,196);
    hline(4,15,76,196);
    hline(4,18,76,196);
    vline(42,9,21,179);
    printxy(5,9,"Unique Ticket Identifier Code: ");
    printxy(5,10,"Format: UTIC# (e.g. UTIC7)");
    printxy(5,12,"Full Name: ");
    printxy(5,14,"Age: ");
    printxy(5,16,"Destination: ");
    printxy(5,17,"0 - SGP, 1 - ESP, 2 - HAW, 3 - KOR");
    printxy(5,19,"Class: ");
    printxy(5,20,"A - FIRST, B - BUS, C - ECO");
    //Asks user for information.
    while(ans!='N'){
        textfile=fopen("ticket list.txt", "a");
        //Clears text field.
        printxy(44,9,"                    ");
        printxy(44,12,"                    ");
        printxy(44,14,"                    ");
        printxy(44,16,"                    ");
        printxy(44,19,"                    ");
        gotoxy(44,9);
        scanf(" \n");
        //Asks user for UTIC/Unique Ticket Identifier Code.
        gets(utic);
        gotoxy(44,12);
        //Asks user for full name.
        gets(name);
        gotoxy(44,14);
        //Asks user for age.
        scanf("%d",&age);
        gotoxy(44,16);
        //Asks user for destination.
        destinationAsk=getch();
        //Checks which destination the user has inputted. 0 = Singapore, 1 = Spain, 2 = Hawaii, USA, and 3 = South Korea. Anything else will be "Unknown".
        if(destinationAsk=='0'){
            strcpy(destination, "Singapore");
            //Prints "Singapore" on the destination field. Same goes to the other destinations but what it prints varies accordingly.
            printxy(44,16,"Singapore");
        }
        else if(destinationAsk=='1'){
            strcpy(destination, "Spain");
            printxy(44,16,"Spain");
        }
        else if(destinationAsk=='2'){
            strcpy(destination, "Hawaii, US");
            printxy(44,16,"Hawaii, US");
        }
        else if(destinationAsk=='3'){
            strcpy(destination, "South Korea");
            printxy(44,16,"South Korea");
        }
        else{
            strcpy(destination, "Unknown");
            printxy(44,16,"Unknown");
        }
        //Asks the user for class type.
        classTypeAsk=toupper(getch());
        if(classTypeAsk=='A'){
            strcpy(classType, "First Class");
            //Prints "First Class" on the class type field. Same goes to the other classes but what it prints varies accordingly.
            printxy(44,19,"First Class");
        }
        else if(classTypeAsk=='B'){
            strcpy(classType, "Business Class");
            printxy(44,19,"Business Class");
        }
        else if(classTypeAsk=='C'){
            strcpy(classType, "Economy Class");
            printxy(44,19,"Economy Class");
        }
        else{
            strcpy(classType, "Unknown");
            printxy(44,19,"Unknown");
        }
        //Prints data into the text file.
        fprintf(textfile,"\n%s %s %d %s %s",utic,name,age,destination,classType);
        fclose(textfile);
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
        //Loading animation
        for(int x=4;x<=76;x++)
        {
            gotoxy(x,23);putchar(219);
            Sleep(5);
        }
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
        center(23, "Record has been written to the database. Press 'N' to terminate process.");
        ans=toupper(getch());
        clearportion(4,23,76,23);
    }
} //void insert

void show(void){
    system("cls");
    int singapore, spain, hawaii, southKorea, firstClass, businessClass, economyClass, age, row=10;
    char utic[10], name[20], destination[20], classType[20];
    line2(2,2,78,24);
    line1(3,3,77,5);
    line1(3,7,77,22);
    center(4,"Show Existing Record");
    gotoxy(5,8);
    printf("UTIC\tName\t\t\Age\tDestination\tClass\t\tDate");
    hline(4,9,76,196);
    FILE *textfile;
    textfile=fopen("ticket list.txt", "r");
//  clearportion(4,8,76,21);
    while(fscanf(textfile,"%s %s %d %s %s",utic,name,&age,destination,classType)!=EOF){
//      row=10;
//      clearportion(4,23,76,23);
//      gotoxy(5,8);
        printxy(5,8,"UTIC\tName\t\t\Age\tDestination\tClass\t\tDate");
        gotoxy(5,row);
//      printf("%s %s %d %s %s",utic,name,age,destination,classType);
        printf("%s",utic);
        gotoxy(15,row);
        printf("%s",name);
        gotoxy(25,row);
        printf("%d",age);
        gotoxy(35,row);
        printf("%s",destination);
        gotoxy(45,row);
        printf("%s",classType);
        row++;
    }//while
    
    
    getch();
    fclose(textfile);
}

main(void){
    char option;
    //Main Screen
    while(option!='F'){
        system("cls");
        line1(3,3,77,7);
        line2(2,2,78,24);
        line1(3,9,77,22);
        center(4, "Flight Ticket Listing Software");
        center(5, "v.1.0.1.12 alpha");
        center(6, "(C) Job Enriquez"); 
        center(11, "Option Selected: ");
        //Options
        printxy(26,14,"(A) Generate a new file");
        printxy(26,15,"(B) Insert new record");
        printxy(26,16,"(C) Show existing records");
        printxy(26,17,"(D) Search for a record");
        printxy(26,18,"(E) Back up existing file");
        printxy(26,19,"(F) Exit program");
        gotoxy(49,11);
        //Asks user which option they desire.
        option=toupper(getche());
        //Checks which option they chose. 'A' generates a new file, 'B' inserts new records, 'C' shows existing records, 'D' backs up existing file, and 'F' terminates program.
        if(option=='A'){
            generate();
        }
        else if(option=='B'){
            insert();
        }
        else if(option=='C'){
            show();
        }
    } //while   
}
```

Comment: You should post the contents of your data file. I suspect you have spaces in your data (like in the names).

Comment: You are right, absolutely no C++ at all. You should talk to the school authorities.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/r2t5HLL

this is what the text file looks like

Comment: Give your teacher this link, and tell him that he only should give C++ lessons after studying this : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines. I guess a lot of use here would like to talk to him too.

Comment: @JobEnriquez Well hat's the problem, your input has spaces in the names, but the code you have does not read spaces.

Comment: Aight, I'll try separating them.

Answer (score 0):

Show your teacher this, this is what C++ looks like to load and display the content of the file. (As you can see it is nothing like the code he has shown to you)
The regex is there to deal with the input (some countries are two words, so splitting by space won't get correct results)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  // file io with streams 
#include <sstream>  // to let a stringstream stand in for a file stream
#include <string>   // to avoid "C" style strings
#include <regex>    // for parsing input file
#include <vector>   // for creating a resizable array

std::istringstream file_stream
{
    "UTIC0 Jose Santos 10 Spain First Class\n"
    "UTIC2 Juna Cruz 18 South Korea Economy Class\n"
};

// always model data that needs to be consistent
// as one struct, not as a seperate list of arrays or something.
struct PassengerInfo
{
    std::string flight_id;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string country;
    std::string class_level;
};

// overload operator << on ostream, so we can easily output
// passenger info to std::cout later
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PassengerInfo info)
{
    os << "=============================\n";
    os << "Passenger info : \n";
    os << "flight id = " << info.flight_id << "\n";
    os << "first name = " << info.first_name << "\n";
    os << "last name = " << info.last_name << "\n";
    os << "age = " << info.age << "\n";
    os << "country = " << info.country << "\n";
    os << "class = " << info.class_level << "\n";
    os << "=============================\n";

    return os;
}

// input will not be consistent, country could be two words
// but the last bit will be Econoy or first class
// so to properly read the file I think using a regex is
// the way to go.
// Regex in action here : https://regex101.com/r/nwCo9C/1
const static std::regex rx{ "([\\w|\\d]{5}) (\\w+) (\\w+) (\\d+) (.*?) (First Class|Economy Class)$" };

std::vector<PassengerInfo> LoadFromStream(std::istream& stream)
{
    std::vector<PassengerInfo> passengers;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(stream,line))
    {
        std::smatch match;
        if (std::regex_match(line, match, rx))
        {
            PassengerInfo info{};   // zero initialize PassengerInfo
            info.flight_id = match[1]; // first matched group
            info.first_name = match[2];
            info.last_name = match[3];
            info.age = std::stoul(match[4]); // convert string to integer
            info.country = match[5];
            info.class_level = match[6];

            passengers.push_back(info);
        }

    }

    return passengers;
}


int main()
{
    // replace the file_stream (stringstream) with this in real code
    // std::ifstream file_stream{"student.txt"};
    auto passengers = LoadFromStream(file_stream);

    // show all read data
    // this is a range based for loop 
    // and is safe to use then an index based for loop
    // which can go out of bounds.

    for (const auto& passenger : passengers) // the const means this loop cant change the content of passenger data
    {
        std::cout << passenger;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think the teacher will read this, repent, and embark on the journey to C++ enlightenment? Ha ha, twice. My advice is to walk out of the class and never look back. If impossible, do the bare minimum to get a passing grade, forget everything that was taught, and never look back.

Comment: I don't have the guts to confront him with this. I'll just let the semestre pass, but thank you all very much!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. No ofcourse not... But at least OP now knows what difference there is

Comment: You can still confront him after your exam and report sub quality education to your institute

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm not sure if I will still study C++ after this semester. I might just skip it and learn Python instead. But, who knows. I might still learn it in the future.

Comment: My remark wasn't necessarily about c++, it is about the quality of education. 
When I was at university I had a bad teacher for linear algebra (for which we were supposed to hand in mandatory assigments too) In the end I complained at the factulty/my mentor, and the teacher was given feedback and only had to pass the exam (which I did). But that was my path, doesn't have to be yours.  Anyway good luck with your education!